# How can I logout from Facebook or clear cookies on WebAuthenticationBroker?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-8, logout

I am using this function for logout on Facebook;

```
WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, new Uri(logOutUrl));
```

I have never logout yet. Tested logoutUrls;

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=ms-app://s-1-15-2-3770417266-2318136516-104659947-271617402-3372047-3177875635-1623475580/&access_token=CAAWBicfyTKIBAKP1Y3SqwsmifvM8IzC8mEVudOtlkQ2vTZB2ZCVGIV4rlJGYAtHSZCE3llAE4APTwPkO01DrsGO15TvvhvxfE0ZCVZA9KaqzHOIr4gRJaBvStN5ZAFBOkgUnAh8MVDYySpcw6tg7wAi3tdSctyFScHyvC9IexktnZCCh8VIveGKA1iP3LpG2b9pZBUOQsYCxLKZBVmqSjLHN4AissXi6vqL5TTz06mUFRmKZBvxrWouEkoTaju0xDYk4gZD

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&access_token=CAAWBicfyTKIBAImjTd00l36CxXBKTg47IZCOApW5f8jaOZCZBc3K8DZCdUQYABsRqCRq2Q9NurBHdBBqEuEarCKDT6HGHmqLQNQ1xLsZBGSuuZAEMiSfP95jeta4IkS4GHvnue8rJxiflIeXpBQ6VWC0BtaEYLBBqaelpTwEo9uWOgcISMGXDWt51r8n0JWqnH4JaJJD0cbmm1vTt06nH4m1S9pEeFBCcZD

What is my mistake ? I have to set any setting in developer.facebook.com ?

Comment: Please add details about the incorrect behavior you are seeing. Explain why you believe that code and those links are not working. What errors are you getting (if any).

Comment: When I call this urls all the time facebook redirect to https://www.facebook.com/home.php . but I expect to redirect login page

Answer (score 1):

Few things based on the limited information you've provided:
With trying to complete a clean logout with the web authentication broker, your second tried url is closer to the mark, however it has some issues:

The start is correct: **"https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?"**

the logout re-direct url passed on the query string as the parameter [next]
which contains: **"login_success.html"**
needs to be url encoded. 
(other wise you get redirected to the home page which is what your finding)

the access token I'll assume this is correct.

when you call it you will end up on the blank page, with the words success on it, and a happy warning message from Facebook, that you should be careful passing, the access token, on the query string.

But it's not problem because that data isn't accessible by the end user.  When using the web authentication broker.

The next issue you will encounter after, after fixing the url encoding, is that the user is left at this ugly page, with a Facebook security warning message, where the user has to click the back navigation button on their device to return to the application, which isn't ideal, nor does the Facebook warning page tell the end user to do that.

So to counter act this state the web authentication broker as different method to fire the logout request and detect the callback state.

so it's best to show you with some code:)

```
    _logoutUrl = FBClient.GetLogoutUrl(new
        {
            next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
            access_token = //your access token (string)
        });

        var url = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect");

            WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(_logoutUrl, url);
```

you will see that I used WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue as opposed to AuthenticateAsync this is because with the authenticate and continue, this allows us to provide the method, with a second uri / url that is used under the hood, in the fashion, that if the authentication process results, in a url that (starts with / contains), the second url that we have provided, then this is the indicator, to pull the response back to our app, automatically.

so for the code above, the wab (short for web authentication broker) will fire up it's internal web-view control and navigate to the Facebook logout url, as you already know, and when the logout completes it will redirect the webview to the url: containing "login_success.html", and the second that happens the (wab) will detect that our url that was provided as the second parameter https://www.facebook.com/connect is apart of that and return back to the application. And the Facebook auth tokens/cookies will be cleared.